# Como puedo obtener los tres precios mas altos de mi tabla en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

necesito hacer una consulta a mi BD en donde traiga:
- Los 3 precios mas altos (si hay dos precios iguales tienen que ser 4 en total)
- Ordenarlos de menor a mayor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer eso?
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Has probado alguna cosa? Tienes que poner lo que hayas probado para que tu pregunta no termine cerrada por falta de información

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT price, name FROM
( 
SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES price, name
FROM Tabla
ORDER BY price
) A
ORDER BY price desc
```

Hacer un **select top with ties** te permite seleccionar los 3 primeros valores incluyendo empates.
Para que muestre el orden al revés hay que hacer después una ordenación en sentido contrario a la tabla resultante.

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias me funciono correctamente, Una ultima pregunta, Para que sirve el "A" al final de la subconsulta?

Comment: "A" no es más que un alias para identificar a la subconsulta en caso de que sea necesario referenciarla en alguna otra parte de la consulta.